# Show text inside div but treat it as a background image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div which has the initial text `loading...` inside of it, and can later be overlapped by new elements that are loaded into it. Here's what I'm dealing with:

```
<div class="results" style="position:relative;" *ngIf="showResults">
    <!-- show 'loading...' before the results load, which would then overlap this text -->
    <div stlye="position: absolute; z-index: -1;">Loading ...</div>
    <!-- angular2 loop to asynchronously load results -->
    <div *ngFor="let loc of searchLocations | async" (click)="selectLocation(loc)" class="search-result">
        {{ loc.name }}, {{ loc.adminName1 }}, {{ loc.countryCode }}
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I run this, here's what I get something like

[image]

so my 'loading...' text has it's own boundry, when i want those proceeding elements to overlap ontop of that text. How can I accomplish something like this?

Comment: you spelled style as `stlye`...  that might do it.

Comment: you could add an ngIf on your loading-div and hide it once you got data.

Comment: @andi lol thanks, although it doesn't cover the loading text, just overlap it. What do I need to add the search result element to make it completely opaque?

Comment: Its not good practice by overlapping loding... div using css. I agree with kkreft solution.

Comment: @Sharmila problem is that I'm using rxjs observables, which has an on-going bug which doesn't allow me to check the length of the stream (meaning I don't know when it's loading)

Comment: did you try giving it an opaque background color?  (if so, could you create a fiddle with the final compiled code, to replicate the issue?)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a boolean for the loader.

```
export class YourClass(){
   isLoading:boolean = true;
   constructor(){
       // Not sure how you are implementing your GET Request
       // So no point in trying to replicate that, just where ever
       // you assign searchLocations to an object
       // fetch data logic ends with => {
          isLoading = false;
       } 
   }
}
```

Then in your html you just need to add an *ngIf

```
 <div style="position: absolute; z-index: -1;" 
      *ngIf="isLoading">Loading ...</div>
```

You could even even make the loader a component to use anywhere, or you could hook into the showResults variable, as long as you place the loading div outside the showResults div with an attribute of *ngIf="!showResults" , which might mean a bit of a style tweek.